# Multiple IMAP accounts Outlook 2011

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-office, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have a Mac running OSX Lion and office Home and Business 2011.  I need to have a couple of IMAP accounts hooked up but am unable to get this functioning properly.  When I connect the first IMAP account it works fine, but subsequent accounts will not connect it gives me an error.  Any thoughts?

Thanks
msindle

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: It says that the username and password are not correct and it cannot add the account.  I know the username and password are correct because I reset them several times.

Answer (score 0):

Though IMAP is quite powerful, it is also rather fragile. It is quite likely that you need to adjust the settings in order to get the IMAP server to recognise your log-in. Rest assured that Outlook is quite good at this - though only in the latest versions. Old versions of Outlook were notoriously bad at following IMAP conventions.

If you can provide some more information, I can update this answer with more specifics. The things to look for are:

- What security settings are needed? This is the most common problem. There are a number of different ways to secure IMAP servers, all with slightly different settings.
- What IMAP server type are you connecting to? e.g. Dovecot, GMail, etc. This makes a difference to the settings used.
- What are the namespace settings used on the server? This will probably be answered by the question above. IMAP allows folder use but there are a variety of ways that the folders can be configured.

Comment: Ok I have made adjustments and now I no longer get the error message.  Now it only shows one imap account in my "folder list" at the left.  I can add each one individual but not more than one.

Comment: Please disregard this post, somehow it started working.  Maybe it need time to sync?...odd  Thank you for your help!